# MGRS Errors: String Error

Tags: python, string

dear friends!

I'm supposed to use a [MGRS-library](https://pypi.org/project/mgrs/)  but I'm stuck on this issue:

```
import mgrs
m = mgrs.MGRS()
d = m.toLatLon('15TWG0000049776')
print(d)
```

The console says:
*mgrs.core.RTreeError: Error in "Convert_MGRS_To_Geodetic": MGRS Errors: String Error*

Comment: Have you seen the [pypi docs](https://pypi.org/project/mgrs/)?

Answer (score 1):

The MGRS library expects bytes literals instead of string. So:

`d = m.toLatLon('15TWG0000049776'.encode())`